# sending refresh token in headers to Laravel backend

Tags: laravel, post, axios, header

Using Postman I'm able to POST my refreshToken:

[image: Postman example].

In my controller I can receive above token like so:

`$request->header('refreshToken');`

If I try to do the same using axios I receive the data in $request->refreshToken not in header

```
axios.post( 
          'mybackend/refreshToken',
          { 'refreshToken': myToken }
      )
```

tried the 'headers' option in axios but no luck.

```
$request->header('refreshToken');  // I should receive the token here, from axios
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are sending the refreshToken in the body instead of the header.
It should be:

```
axios.post( 
          'mybackend/refreshToken',
          {}, //body
          {headers:{ 'refreshToken': myToken }} //header
      )
```